# Finding MEX of a changing set

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to create a method **add** that adds elements **x** to the set one by one and returns MEX (=minimum non-negative number not in the set) of the list at each point.

```
class Mex:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mex = set()

    def add(self, x):
        self.mex.add(x)
        mex = 0
        while mex in self.mex:
            mex += 1
        return mex
```

This is not efficient enough and it's probably because the set changes each time. I have also tried the following but the problem is the same

```
    def add(self,x):   
         self.mex.add(x)
         for i in range(len(self.mex)):
             if i not in self.mex:
                 return i
        
         return len(self.mex)
```

Tips?

Comment: @KellyBundy I thought set would be better.. and MEX = minimum excluded, so what is the smallest non-negative number that isn't in the set

Comment: And `add` is the only operation?

Comment: Is this online somewhere for testing?

Comment: @KellyBundy yes

Comment: @KellyBundy no, I dont think so

Comment: Define your terminology in the question itself, not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't always start from 0 again, remember where you were.

```
class Mex:
    def __init__(self):
        self.added = set()
        self.mex = 0

    def add(self, x):
        self.added.add(x)
        while self.mex in self.added:
            self.mex += 1
        return self.mex
```